# Python 3.x | How to use random.choice() or .sample() to make sure it doesn't pick the same value in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, random

I am a beginner in python and making an english/norwegian dictionary.
 I am trying not to have the same english word come more than once when I run the program.
 I know that this has been answered many times already, but I just can't get the right code for that implemented in the program.
 I would appreciate very much if someone could implement the right code for that problem.
 Here is the code so far:

```
import random
eng_nor = {'one':'en', 'two': 'to', 'three': 'tre', 'four': 'fire', 'five': 'fem', 'six': 'seks', 'seven': 'syv',
           'eight': 'åtte', 'nine': 'ni', 'ten': 'ti'}
print()
print('Number of words in the dictionary: ',len(eng_nor))
print()

eng = list(eng_nor.keys())
print('If you want to exit, type 0')
antall_gloser=int(input('How many words do you want to practice?\n '))
if antall_gloser>len(eng_nor):
    x=len(eng_nor)
    antall_gloser=x
    print('We have just ', x, ' words in the dictionary.')
point = 0

for i in range(antall_gloser):
    eng_ord = random.choice(eng)
    norsk_ord = eng_nor[eng_ord]
    user_guess = input('What is the norwegian word of %s?\n' % eng_ord)
    if user_guess == 0:
        break
    elif user_guess == norsk_ord:
        point += 1
        print('Correct! Your score is %d' % point)
    else:
        print('Wrong. The norwegian word of {} is {}.'.format(eng_ord, norsk_ord))
print('We are done. Your final score is %d, Thank you.' % point)
```

An example of an output I get could be like this:

```
D:\Users\heva\PycharmProjects\test\virtual\Scripts\python.exe D:/Users/heva/PycharmProjects/test/test10.py

Number of words in the dictionary:  10

If you want to exit, type 0
How many words do you want to practice?
 3
What is the norwegian word of two?
to
Correct! Your score is 1
What is the norwegian word of two?
to
Correct! Your score is 2
What is the norwegian word of seven?
syv
Correct! Your score is 3
We are done. Your final score is 3, Thank you.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you see in this example, two of the english words are the same....
 Any help would be highly appreciated..
 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [shuffled version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) of your dictionaries keys:

```
import random

eng_nor = {'one':'en', 'two': 'to', 'three': 'tre', 'four': 'fire', 'five': 'fem',
           'six': 'seks', 'seven': 'syv', 'eight': 'åtte', 'nine': 'ni', 'ten': 'ti'}

eng = list(eng_nor.keys())
random.shuffle(eng)  # inplace shuffling

how_much = 5

# take only the first 5 of the shuffled key-list
for key in eng[:how_much]: 
    value = eng_nor[key]
    if input(f"Translate '{key}': ") == value:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print(f"Wrong. {key} == {value}")
```

By shuffling the key list, it is guaranteed that each key is still only choosen once. And using list-slicing won't raise an error if you "overstep":

```
k = [1,2,3,4]

for elem in k[:2000]:
    print(k)   # prints 1 to 4 each in a new line
```

You can do the same using [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) but you need to respect the maximal key count:

```
how_much = 9999
# reduce k if needed to the maximum length of your keys() 
eng2 = random.sample(eng_nor.keys(), k = min(len(eng_nor),how_much) )
```